# three.js morphTarget animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, blender

Similar to this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446481/how-is-morphtarget-exported-from-blender-and-imported-into-threejs-as-separate-a) I am trying to control morphTarget animation , exported via .json file( from Blender (2.73) to THREE.js(R73))--The result is an array of morph targets, one for each frame. This is shape-key animation (facial expressions)--it is my understanding that you cannot target actions/skinned animations without skeleton/armatures in Three.js/is this correct? The morph example ofGinger (https://sv-ginger.appspot.com/) is via Maya export, and a few years earlier. Is it possible to target frames within the morph targets array and start/stop, etc? With earlier iterations of THREE.js this worked differently. Any examples, suggestions, etc would be most appreciated!